# IDFA automatically in Google Analytics for Firebase?

Tags: ios, firebase, google-analytics, idfa

I'm working on a free app that has been live for 4 years. It has no ads or purchases of any kind. Just a free app.

There is no advertising of any kind, so we have always registered that we do not use IDFA when distributing on AppStore.

We have recently implemented Google Analytics for Firebase, and during our Beta we noticed that Analytics reports the gender of our users. How?

Based on [this Firebase-reference](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317486?hl=en) it seems that Firebase uses IDFA.
It states that `When the Device Advertising ID is not present, Analytics cannot derive demographics and interests information.` This identifier shouldn't be available for any of our users, since we literally don't have anything resembling an ad-implementation.

Obviously, I have no idea what IDFA is, and don't understand why this is happening. I am wondering - should we now start to select "Yes - we use IDFA" when distributing? Or can we disable Analytics's use of IDFA? What impact will it have?